# ESLint does not find meteor rules in Atom.io in first line

Tags: javascript, meteor, atom-editor, eslint

I just set up ESlint in Atom.io for my project and it works fine for all cases like code guidelines and static code errors. But some how I got these errors in **all** files in the **first** line:

```
ESLint Error meteor/audit-argument-checks Definition for rule 'meteor/audit-argument-checks' was not foundat line 1 col 1
ESLint Error meteor/no-session Definition for rule 'meteor/no-session' was not foundat line 1 col 1
ESLint Error meteor/no-template-lifecycle-assignments Definition for rule 'meteor/no-template-lifecycle-assignments' was not foundat line 1 col 1
ESLint Error meteor/no-zero-timeout Definition for rule 'meteor/no-zero-timeout' was not foundat line 1 col 1
ESLint Error meteor/eventmap-params Definition for rule 'meteor/eventmap-params' was not foundat line 1 col 1
ESLint Error meteor/template-names Definition for rule 'meteor/template-names' was not foundat line 1 col 1
```

My first line is usally:

```
//First line of code 
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

But it doesn't matter what I write, the errors are always the same. Did I forget to set something? Do I need to define these rules manually?

My .eslint.rc is this:

```
module.exports = {
    "plugins": ["meteor"],
    "extends": [
      "plugin:meteor/recommended",
      "eslint:recommended",
    ],
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "meteor": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "installedESLint": true,
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": "meteor"
    },
    "rules": {
      "max-len": 0,
      "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    }
};
```

Comment: For those still struggeling: This was a bug in the linter. Should ne solved wth a never version